# Why isn't my php json_encode not serializable with .responseJSON in alamofire?

Tags: php, ios, json, swift, alamofire

I'm having some trouble with serialization on a JSON response on my iOS app from my server, its a PHP back-end. My app sends a post request with the appropriate parameters, validates them, puts the results in an array, and encodes it in. Now that's not the problem, code works fine. However, its the link between them. Look at the PHP code below.

```php
echo json_encode($array)
```

Now coming to xcode, I'm using alamofire to send the request as seen in the code below

```swift
Alamofire.request(URL_USER_REGISTER, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseString { response in
            print(response)
            }
        }
```

As you can see its in .responseString because I apparently if I use .responseJSON it throws a code=3480 error and I want to get specific data from my own response JSON. I tried other ways to fix this online, but they all choose the .responseString option.

Why is this happening? Are the JSON types incompatible? Is there a secret to this?

I just want to get specific data from my JSON response such as "message" and its not possible when i get a string... Any help is appreciated!

I'm using Alamofire 4.3

Comment: `Look at the PHP code below.` This line doesn't print the resulting json string.

Comment: @tkausl sorry about that, look at the edited code

Comment: yes and it didn't work, I keep getting that 3480 error code when attempting to read, I guess I'm going to have to cheat myself into getting the info from the string

Comment: Are you sure you aren't getting a 3840 error, which would be an invalid JSON error? There is no error 3480. And if you're somehow seeing it, could you post the `localizedDescription`. Also, Alamofire 4.3 is years out of date, you should at least update to 4.8.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following so Alamofire will run the response data through `JSONSerialization`, depending on the type of JSON response you can use either `json as? [String : Any]` or `json as? [[String : Any]]`

```
Alamofire.request(URL, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { response in
    guard response.error == nil, let json = response.result.value else {
        print("Error: \(response.error?.localizedDescription ?? "no content")")
        return
    }

    if let jsonDict = json as? [String : Any] {
        print(jsonDict)
    } else if let jsonArray = json as? [[String : Any]] {
        print(jsonArray)
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG that actually worked! Thank u so much! I don't get it tho, why can't it accept a json object directly instead of converting it locally? Maybe a bug? :/

Comment: Well I meant it as a minor bug in the library but thats ok, what you suggested works :D

Comment: This is just doing what `responseJSON` already does: get the data, run it through `JSONSerialization` with the `.allowFragments` option. There should be no behavioral difference. What bug are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried printing the `response.value` to check it it's a valid JSON?

Comment: Where did you get code=3480, did the program crash or was that an error from Alamofire?

Comment: that was an alamofire error, I've been reading on it and apparently its a bug

Comment: Is there something special about the JSON in the response?

Comment: SUCCESS: {
    error = 0;
    message = "User created successfully";
}

That's the response, pretty basic

Comment: I'm pretty sure that isn't valid JSON.

Comment: It is, I've tested it on other programs I've done, and I accept it as a JSON like any other, but it wont on alamofire

Comment: According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types_and_syntax) and several online JSON linters, the string `SUCCESS: { error = 0; message = "User created successfully"; }` is not a valid JSON object. Even with modifications to wrap it in curly braces, add quotation marks to all strings, and change all the equal signs to colons, it is still not a valid JSON because only commas are used to delimit between objects, not semicolons.

Comment: That's not the JSON output, that the decoded dictionary from `JSONSerialization`.